# merge the two accounts that have my nickname

Tags: support, status-completed

my former open ID provider, openidfrance.fr , is down, so I can't login into my account. The account from which I'm posting right now was automatically created when usind SO's openid I guess.
Can someone merge the two accounts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Done. Both OpenIDs are associated with your [main account](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/653/greg0ire) now, so either one will let you login. If `openidfrance.fr` is down permanently, you can [remove it from your profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22223/how-do-i-remove-my-primary-openid)

Comment: Thank you. I must add that I tried recovering my main account from several email addresses (did not recall which was the right one), and that when I tried then correct address, I got on the error page.

Comment: @greg0ire Strange. I tried it just now with my e-mail and it worked fine (although it wouldn't have helped -- it just tells you your OpenID, it doesn't let you change it). If it still happens for you you might want to file a separate bug about it

Comment: tried again, failed again. I reported the bug here : http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/699/error-page-when-trying-to-recover-my-account