# Same user but two different accounts - Miraaj

Tags: support

For me it is showing two accounts:

Primary Account: https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/29378/miraaj

Other Account: https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/29377/miraaj

Can my other account, along with posted question, be merged with my primary account?

My request is similar to this post: [merge the two accounts that have my nickname](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/697/merge-the-two-accounts-that-have-my-nickname)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your primary account has a lot of reputation on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/217586/miraaj), so mods can't do the merge; a developer will handle it sometime soon and then [this account](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/29378/miraaj) will have the question you asked